# How to use "to go" when I ask in a restaurant?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, conversation, informal-language

When I want to take the food out of a restaurant so that I can eat it at home ( not in the restaurant), how can I ask this to a waitress?
I heard people ask me " for here or to go ?" a lot, so I assumed I have to use "to go" to ask this question but I'm not sure how to use it in a sentence if I'm the one who's asking about it first.

What I came up with are those:

" Can I take out the food to go?"
" Can I have the food to go?"
" Can I order the food to go?"

Do they sound okay?
Is there any better way to ask this?

Comment: I've never heard *..for here or to go...* at least in India. The commonest way to ask is (and now I think a clear way as well!) - *'Sir, here or parcel?'* **or** *'Sir, here or take away?'*

Comment: _A sandwich to go, please_

Comment: @MaulikV It is common in the US.

Comment: For the record, we say 'to take away' in England, and I believe the Scots say 'carry-out'.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I order the food to go?

is a very common usage. Normally you would make such request at the time of ordering, so using *order* is better than *have*.

In:

> Can I **take out** the food **to go**?

*take out* and *to go* basically mean the same thing so this statement comes across as repetitive.

However, *take out* is often use as an adjective describing a kind of food:

> Maybe we should eat **take-out food** tonight.

This form is usually hyphenated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are at the time of ordering, drop the "can." Remember: you are the customer, and customer is the king; that doesn't mean we will get anything for free.

However, if you want to sound more polite, use it. But I never say it.

Say:

> Two medium mushroom-and-cheese pizza, two large coke. Please pack it.

Or the way you want it:

> Two medium mushroom-and-cheese pizza, two large coke, **to go**.

Just present your list of food and say "to go" at the end. That's how it usually works.

You can also say, "can I take this away with me?"

With a hyphen, "to go" can also be used as an adjective, as follows:

> Hey, can you please get me a **to-go** burger?